# Can I find out how many enemies I have killed

Tags: achievements, blade-kitten

There is an achievement for Blade Kitten that requires me to defeat 5000 enemies.

> **Unfriendly Fire**
>
> Defeat 5,000 enemies

I've found no kill counter in the game. Is there a way to know how many kills I've already got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible. In this [official forum thread](http://www.bladekitten.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=336&p=830), a developer states that this wasn't included due to lack of resources.